# Attachment is getting blank while sending email via Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, apex-email-service

I have created the below class for sending an email from Apex

```
public with sharing class GivingStatementControllerNew {

@AuraEnabled
public static boolean sendEmail() 
{
    String [] toAddresses = new List<String>{'test@test.com'};
    //EmailMessage activeEmail = [SELECT ReplyToEmailMessageId FROM EmailMessage WHERE id=:messageId];
    // Create an email
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    
    
    email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    String emailsBody = 'test';
    String emailsSubject = 'test';
    emailsBody = emailsBody.replace('<p>', '<div>');
    emailsBody = emailsBody.replace('</p>', '</div>');

    if(emailsBody != null && emailsBody != '') email.setHtmlBody(emailsBody);
    if(emailsSubject != null && emailsSubject != '') email.setSubject(emailsSubject);
    PageReference pdf =  Page.GivingStatementNew;
    Blob b;
    if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
        b = blob.valueOf('Unit.Test');
    } else {
        b = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
    }
    
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
    efa.setContentType('application/pdf');
    efa.setFileName('Giving Statement.pdf');
    efa.setInline(false);
    efa.setBody(b);
    
    email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

    //if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        try {
            system.debug('-Sending..........-');
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
            system.debug('-Sent');
        } catch (System.EmailException ee) {
            throw new AuraHandledException('Error: ' + ee.getMessage());
        }
    //}
    return true;
}
}
```

Visualforce page

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    Test Page<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    test pdf value
</apex:page>
```

But when I send an email for this I am getting a blank attachment

Comment: I have just copied your code and executed from Developer Console and received an email with attachment which is not blank. Did you try to execute this code from a LWC component?

Comment: Tried again to execute your code within an lwc and also received attachment with non blank body

Comment: did you execute this code under user who doesn't have access to the particular VF page? have you tried to execute the code under admin or grant access to the page to the user?

Comment: I have executed the code with the lightning component for one org and it did not work but for another org, it worked so not sure what is the issue. I am working in the Service based company so we have different salesforce clients. I have submitted the case with salesforce as well but they said this is a code issue and in the basic support they can not debug the issue and routed us this way.